# NSURLSession: handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession method doesn't run in Background session

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, nsurlsession

`application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` doesn't run when the uploads are finished in the background. When all the upload/download tasks are completed in the background then iOS should wake up the app and call the above method. But it doesn't.

1. I have tested this by terminating the app from 'xcode stop' button and also terminated from an exception.
2. I have followed [Background Transfer consideration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44).
3. I have tested this on [Apple developer guide: Background example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html) and it is not working.
4. I have also tested this on [AppCoda: Background example](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/) and it is not working
5. Both of the examples which are given in 2 and 3 points are not working on iOS 9.0 and xCode 7.0. Before upgrading to iOS9.0, I had tested this on iOS7.0 and xcode 5.0 where it ran perfectly.
6. I am assuming that it would work on the real device.

What am I missing here? Can anybody confirm whether `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` works in iOS9.0 simulator or am I doing anything wrong? Since it doesn't work for the examples given in 2 and 3 so I guess maybe I am testing it wrong.

Comment: even if, completionHandler called you can't perform UI related task, insert something in file on call of completionHandler and check

Comment: @sheshnath: I do not follow you completely. What is about "_insert something in the file on call of completionHandler and check_". Also, I do not understand why does the method`application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` is not called upon tasks completion in the background for the examples given in 2nd and 3rd bullet.

Comment: create one file, on call of completionHandler insert text in file "completionHandler called in background" and later check in file for text "completionHandler called in background"

Comment: @sheshnath - It is not working. The file doesn't get created. Also, the `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` is called when the session is restored on restarting the app.

Comment: According to my notes, I saw URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:session
 being called, even though handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession was not called. This was on iOS 9.3.1 (on device, I don't expect this sort of thing to work perfectly on the simulator), when the app was in the background but the "lock screen was not on". That last bit is vague - it's from my notes, and I think it means that I backgrounded the app, but the screen was still on - but I don't know.

Comment: background download events don't fire on a simulator. You can *only* test this on a real device

Answer (score 1):

@ZayinKrige answered this in a comment:

> background download events don't fire on a simulator. You can only test this on a real device

And to expand a bit, here's a guide for testing background session code:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/42353#42353

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause of this was that I was using `uploadTask(withStreamedRequest:...)`, which is not compatible with background URL sessions. I switched to use `uploadTask(with:request, fromFile:...)` instead and everything started working.